# How to grep double quote followed by a string at same time?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

```
   [["QUALITY",**"AVM",200**,610865413,1,0,7,2,-1],[5,0,0,0,0,2],
   [0.998286,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],["aq04rvtcmgff8"],
   [["QUALITY",**"AVM",200**,610865413,1,0,7,2,-1],[5,0,0,0,0,2],
   [0.998286,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],["aq04rvtcmgff8"]
   [["QUALITY",**"AVM",200**,610865413,1,0,7,2,-1],[5,0,0,0,0,2],
   [0.998286,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],["aq04rvtcmgff8"]
   [["QUALITY","AVM”,100,610865413,1,0,7,2,-1]
```

This is the log i have. I want to grep the pattern as follow:

```
**"AVM",200** - In the above log, how many time this pattern comes. Result should be **3**
```

I have tried:

```
**grep "\"AVM\",200" <file> | wc -l** --> but its not giving perfect result
```

Comment: `grep` has an option `-c` to give count of number of lines matching the given string... try `grep -c '"AVM",200'`

Comment: from your formatting, it is not clear if input is single or multiple lines... if it is one line, try `grep -o '"AVM",200' log | wc -l`

Comment: Perfect! @Sundeep -- works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is single match per line, use `-c` option

```
grep -c '"AVM",200' log
```

If there are multiple matches, print one match per line and then count number of lines (depends on `grep` implementation, not all have `-o` option)

```
grep -o '"AVM",200' log | wc -l
```

Or use `GNU awk` to set the search string as record separator and use number of records to get count

```
awk -v RS='"AVM",200' 'END{print NR-1}' log
# to handle empty input as well
awk -v RS='"AVM",200' 'END{print (NR>1?NR-1:0)}'
```

Or count number of occurrences per line

```
awk -F'"AVM",200' 'NF{total += NF-1} END{print total+0}' log
```

Comment: The file is multiple lines. Kind of big log. "AVM", 200 can come at anywhere in the log.